# How to add and concate two variables in same list

Tags: python-3.x

```
array = [[1676, 196, 159, 29, 'invoice'], [1857, 198, 108, 28, 'date:']]

width = 159+108 = 267
height = 29+28 = 57
label = invoice date:

Required solution: [1676, 196, 267, 57, 'invoice date:']
```

Is there any solution to concatenate string and add numbers in same list

Comment: I'm confused, you want to add numbers together from each list, but your solution has 2 numbers from `array[0]` and 2 numbers from `array[1]`

Comment: Use the built-in function [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your other lines are for your own notes/testing, and your "required solution" is a typo, you can use `zip` like so:

```
array = [[1676, 196, 159, 29, 'invoice'], [1857, 198, 108, 28, 'date:']]

res = []

for x, y in zip(array[0], array[1]):    # compare values at each index
    if isinstance(x, str):              # check to see if x is a string
        res.append(x + ' ' + y)         # add a space if x is a string
    else:
        res.append(x + y)               # add the two integers if x is not a string

print(res)
```

```
[3533, 394, 267, 57, 'invoice date:']
```

Note that the concatenation above will only work if you are sure that the same indices will have strings vs. integers.